# Remove data frames containing NA in Large list of data frames

Tags: r, na

I have a Large list containing 470 data frames and 3 columns, each row containing expandable embedded list. I am not sure how to replicate here, so I try my best:

```
Name    Type                             Value
1       list[4]                          List of length 4
  M1      list[4x3](S3:data.frame)         A data.frame with 4 rows and 3 columns
  M2      list[2x3](S3:data.frame)         A data.frame with 2 rows and 3 columns

2       list[2]                          List of length 2
  M1      list[3x3])S3:data.frame)         A data.frame with 3 rows and 3 columns
```

...

```
71      logical                          NA
```

... etc, both M1 and M2 are also expandable.

I would like to remove all rows in which the Value is "NA" (ie. row 71 is removed). 
I have tried manual inspection of the list and applied:

```
df2 <- df1[-c(71,91,97,107,140,143,157,175,178,210,250,262,277,286,
    355,363,382,385,401,404,449),]
```

But only return:

```
Error in MS1[-c(71, 91, 97, 107, 140, 143, 157, 175, 178, 210, 250, 262,  : 
incorrect number of dimensions
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `purrr::modify_depth` and `dplyr::filter` might be what you are after. So does the list always have two data.frames in each element?

Comment: @zacdav No, it's variable